# How to send two post parameters with a button tag?

Tags: html, css, forms, post

I've got two button tags, one for removing and other to adding. With that actions I need to send two parameters via post. What should I do with a  tag to send two params with using post?

Comment: <button> can have a name and a value. However if you're trying to send 2 values, this is done javascript or by making 2 forms, each with a hidden field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your going to have to send a post request using JavaScript & jQuery. Below is a super simple example, more information about `jQuery $.post` can be found [here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/).

```
$.post( "test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" })
  .done(function( data ) {
    alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
  });
```